# Get wordpress latest posts outside the blog

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get latest wordpress posts on a static page outside the wordpress. I'm trying following code but it does not work (ie. I do not get any output).

```
<?php
    $config_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp/wp-config.php';
    include($config_file); 

    $postlist = get_posts('numberposts=5');
    foreach ($postlist as $post) : ?>
        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wp-config file only stores those variables for use in other scripts. It doesn't define any of the wordpress functions. I believe what you are looking for would be something like this.

```
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
  require('/server/path/to/your/wordpress/site/htdocs/blog/wp-blog-header.php');
```

After that, you should be able to use wordpress functions.